# SSIS - Sharepoint list data transfer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, ssis

Is there a limit on the number of rows that can be transferred from a Oracle database(OLEDB source) to a sharepoint list using SSIS? I am getting exception after transferring 19000 records

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm assuming you are using the API to store the information in SharePoint rather than a direct write to the SQL database. Any [direct access to the database](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikefitz/archive/2005/04/01/404802.aspx) is [unsupported](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841057).

To give a proper answer would require the details of the exception. However:

- Recommended number of items in a list is 2000
- Maximum number supported recommending the use of folders is 5 million

Performance reduces significantly beyond the 2000 mark. This may be what's causing the exceptions. There is information about this on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287790.aspx), from [Joel Oleson](http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=241) (formerly on the MS SharePoint team), and an MS [whitepaper](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=95450&clcid=0x409).

Another possible limit you're reaching is the maximum database size for a site collection, which is 200GB.